# What is the easiest way to get text input from Wix with Python?

Tags: python, web, post, get, velo

I'm doing a service that uses Wix. but now I need to send the input they give through Wix to my Python program. I wish for this to use only or mostly python since I have the best experience in it. I also need to send data back to Wix.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You need to send http requests? What do you mean by "the input they give through Wix"? How is this input done?

Comment: as in the text input element in Wix

Comment: Does wix provide a documentation for their elements? Is it inside a formular that is then submitted and processed? Without seeing the code or any documentation is very hard to guess what you are referring to.

Comment: when you go to your Wix website. you can press 'add element'. then you see the option for input. in the input tab, you can press 'textbox'. that is what I'm referring to